# coredns certificate authority error when starting up k8s over Singularity-CRI

Tags: kubernetes

I am only making my first steps into k8s land so please bare with me...

I am trying to bring up a small k8s cluster with Singularity as the containers runtime. I am following [this procedure](https://slateci.io/blog/kubernetes-with-singularity.html).

The problem is that the coredns pods fail to start, because of the following:

```
Jan 27 07:18:15 cent8ws sycri[1302]: #011Error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not set up pod network interface: error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://[10.96.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
```

I googled up this problem and found that it was raised many times, but none of the suggested soloutions worked for me. I'm not sure if it is related to the fact that I am using Singularity or not...
Please see some details about my system and the status of the ks cluster below.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Oren

---

```
root@cent8ws ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011


[root@cent8ws ~]# rpm -qa | grep -e kub -e sing
webrtc-audio-processing-0.3-9.el8.x86_64
kubelet-1.20.2-0.x86_64
kubectl-1.20.2-0.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-0.8.7-0.x86_64
singularity-3.7.0-1.el8.x86_64
kubeadm-1.20.2-0.x86_64



kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.0.1.0/24 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/singularity.sock --ignore-preflight-errors=All --upload-certs --node-name=$HOSTNAME


Jan 27 07:18:15 cent8ws sycri[1302]: #011Error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not set up pod network interface: error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://[10.96.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")

[root@cent8ws ~]# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-dldl2                       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5m50s
coredns-74ff55c5b-tbhkw                       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5m50s
etcd-cent8ws.localdomain                      1/1     Running             0          5m52s
kube-apiserver-cent8ws.localdomain            1/1     Running             0          5m51s
kube-controller-manager-cent8ws.localdomain   1/1     Running             0          5m51s
kube-proxy-wb62q                              1/1     Running             0          5m50s
kube-scheduler-cent8ws.localdomain            1/1     Running             0          5m52s



root@cent8ws ~]# kubectl describe pods coredns-74ff55c5b-tbhkw --namespace=kube-system
Name:                 coredns-74ff55c5b-tbhkw
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 cent8ws.localdomain/192.168.122.1
Start Time:           Wed, 27 Jan 2021 07:17:47 +0200
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=74ff55c5b
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Pending
IP:                   
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-74ff55c5b
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0
    Image ID:      
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-29225 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  coredns-token-29225:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  coredns-token-29225
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               6m46s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-74ff55c5b-tbhkw to cent8ws.localdomain
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  70s (x26 over 6m45s)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Internal desc = could not set up pod network interface: error getting ClusterInformation: Get "https://[10.96.0.1]:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
```

Comment: Have you tried https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#tls-certificate-errors ?

Comment: Hi, Yes that link is one of the things I looked at. The crtificate looks ok, unless the issuer shouldn't be "kubernetes" or the CN=kubernetes-admin. If this is the case then what the values should be, and how can I change that?

Comment: As I saw repository of Singularity-CRI has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only. See: https://github.com/sylabs/singularity-cri. They are working on new feature, maybe something is wrong with this cri. Can you try another one, for example CRI-O - https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#cri-o ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue. I ran below commands in centos machine.

for image pull latest

```
sudo kubeadm config images pull
```

removed the ip links:

```
ip link list | grep cali | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-15 | xargs -I {} ip link delete {}
```

Try running these step in `master and worker nodes`.

- move or remove the calico file in this location `/etc/cni/net.d`
- restart the kubelete `sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service`

try to delete the not running pod `kubectl delete pods coredns-558bd4d5db-t6d7r -n kube-system` and `kubelet get pods -A`